# React Router useRouterHistory breaks routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history.js

I'm developing an application using React and React-Router. I cannot use browserHistory but have to use hashHistory. Just passing the ReactRouter.hashHistory to the Router history attribute works fine. But since I want to get rid of the `_q` query parameter, I use useRouterHistory like described in the [React-Router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#userouterhistorycreatehistory). Strangely when I do this my app stops to work completely. It looks like no route is actually being called, since no markup is being created.

This is what my routes look like and how I kick off React the router history:

```
var routes = (
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={Countries} />
        <Route path="/country/:id" component={Country} />
      </Route>
    ),
    useRouterHistory = require('react-router').useRouterHistory,
    createHashHistory = require('history').createHashHistory,
    appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({query: false}),
    routes = require('./routes.jsx');


ReactDOM.render( <Router history={appHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('app') );
```

Am I doing it right? Any ideas why the app is not being built?

Comment: Have you tried React Router 4? I find it easier to create a HashRouter: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter (and doesn't come with the _q query param by default)